# vb script recursion and dynamic file naming

Tags: recursion, vbscript

My goal for this project is to have this script perform the following:

1- pop a dialogue asking for a working directory to process

2- create a "text" subdirectory

3- open up a word file, run a word macro on the file, and save it as a text file using the same original filename as the word document

4- Repeat step 3 throughout the entire contents of the directory

So far I have step 3 figured out and tested, save the file naming, which I thought was going to be the hardest part to figure out (getting the word macro to run invisibly) but it runs great.

I've been self teaching python the past few weeks, and hit a wall trying to get the word macro to fire off, tried it in a VBS and bam, worked right off the bat.  But I have no idea how to make this recursive through the entire directory, or take in original filenames with a variable and rename with the same variable.  I realize some of these are basic questions and apologize for that - referring me to documentation to help me learn is absolutely fine here.  My code for this is pasted below for reference to see what I am doing.

Any help in getting it to process the entire directory and keeping the filenames the same (IE document.doc or .docx becomes document.txt) would be fantastic!

Thanks for any and all pointers!

--

```
Dim AppWord

Dim OpenDocument

Const docTXT = 2

Set AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

AppWord.Visible = False

Set OpenDocument = AppWord.Documents.Open("C:\test\doc.docx")

AppWord.Run "macro1"

OpenDocument.SaveAs "C:\test\text\docnowtext", docTXT

OpenDocument.Close
Set OpenDocument = Nothing

AppWord.Quit
Set AppWord = Nothing

MsgBox "All done!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key to making this work is you need to:

- You need to prompt the user, perhaps with `InputBox`
- You can generate filename.txt from filename.docx by doing a Replace on the extension
- <s>Define a `Sub` or `Function` that recursively calls itself</s>
- Implement using [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706(v=vs.60).aspx), [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242698(v=vs.60).aspx) and [Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242710(v=vs.60).aspx) objects
- Whenever you encounter a `.docx` file you process it
- <s>Whenever you encounter a `Subfolder` you use it for recursion</s>
- Added support for both .doc and .docx files

For example:

```
Option Explicit  

Sub DoSomethingWithDOCX(docxpath)
    Dim fso, file, folder, txtpath
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set file = fso.GetFile(docxpath)
    Set folder = file.ParentFolder
    If Not fso.FolderExists(folder + "\text") Then
        Call fso.CreateFolder(folder + "\text")
    End If
    If Right(file.Name, 5) = ".docx" Then
        txtpath = folder & "\text" & "\" & Replace(file.Name, ".docx", ".txt")
    ElseIf Right(file.Name, 4) = ".doc" Then
        txtpath = folder & "\text" & "\" & Replace(file.Name, ".doc", ".txt")
    End If

    ' @@TODO: Do your original code with docxpath and txtpath
End Sub

Sub SearchForDOCX(path)
    Dim fso, file, folder, subfolder, txt
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)
    For Each file in folder.Files
        If right(file.Name, 5) = ".docx" Then
            Call DoSomethingWithDOCX(path + "\" + file.Name)
        ElseIf right(file.Name, 4) = ".doc" Then
            Call DoSomethingWithDOCX(path + "\" + file.Name)
        End If
    Next
    'For Each subfolder in folder.SubFOlders
    '    Call SearchForDOCX(subfolder.Path)
    'Next
End Sub

Dim path
path = InputBox("Specify Folder to process")
Call SearchForDOCX(path)
```

Comment: Oh man, I just realized I used the wrong language her, unintentionally.  My Apologies.  I want to process all files in a single directory, not subfolders, so recursion was the wrong word to use.  I just want my document handling to loop over all files in the directory, keeping the original filename intact save the extension.

Comment: Okay, I've just removed the subfolder from the solution, but, pretty much the original answer is there. i.e. `FileSystemObject` and processing the `Files` in a loop. Also did you see what I was doing with the `Replace()` function to change a `.docx` filename into a `.txt` filename?

Comment: Nice trick with the replace function for sure there, very cool.  Im working out some syntax issues with trying this out right now, will comment back shortly, but wanted to thank you first here!

Comment: I'm fairly certain I am missing something obvious here.  I believe I have this all locked down save the filename structure in the following:

    Set OpenDocument = AppWord.Documents.Open(file)
    AppWord.Run "bolditalic"
    OpenDocument.SaveAs "txtpath", docTXT

I'm getting a mismatch type error on file there, but I believe it is the right information.

Comment: You need to use txtpath **without** the quotes.

Comment: Okay, if I set AppWord.Visible = True I see what is going on.  On the first file opened, it says the file is locked by word (even though it is not otherwise already opened) and throws a dialogue prompting me to choose whether to open a read only copy, create a local copy, be notified when original is available.  If I choose read only the rest of the script fires off on all files without issue.  That said, this is working beautifully and I'm going to accept your answer and thank you a ton here BicycleDude!  Very helpful, nice work!

Comment: I'm also curious if there is a way to have this process a folder containing a mix of .docx and .doc, I can think of this is regex terms like matching (.doc|docx) but I'm not sure how that would apply in vb here.  Again, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Regarding the appword.visible issue, I tried it on a different folder with different word docs and it works fine.  Ill have to track that one down later but that no longer appears to be an issue.

Comment: Yeah regex would be a better way to go for parsing the .doc|.docx files and creating the .txt files. But, meanwhile, since the scenario is simple enough, I show you how to achieve this with `if` statements. It's a little bad because you have to maintain the `if` statement in two location. Some refactoring is required to improve this.

Comment: Ah, I tried moving things around with 2 subroutines and wasn't getting very far.  Thanks for the upgrade there!  Very nicely done.